# Is there anyway to get/remove the first object item like array_shift does on array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I retrieved data, with `mysqli->fetch_object()`, in PHP. How can I get the first item and remove it from the objects, like `array_shift` does to array? How to emulate `array_pop` on `stdClass` also?

Something like:

```
# $object contains 4 items
$first=$object->shift();
$last=$object->pop();
# $object contains 2 items
```

Preferably no other libraries, nor conversions between object and array needed.

Comment: It's probably simpler to fetch an array and shift/pop as required, then you can convert to an object afterwards if required. But this seems like a strange thing to do on a MySQL result row. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Use `get_object_vars()` to get the keys, get the first key, then perform an `unset()` on the property

Comment: I try to create a multi-dimensional json with the 1st item being the key of the 1st dimension. I thought there would be array_shift for object. I searched for it, but all people only mentioned array_shift for array but not for object.

Comment: @Scuzzy that sounds good, do you mind giving examples? Thank you!

Comment: @xam in that case you can just fetch an associative array, you don't need an object, as `json_encode` will convert an associative array into an object when it encodes it.

Comment: Is there a need to use `fetch_object()` over `fetch_array()` then? Simplify your code, mine can't be reduced down any further if you want to play with objects.

Comment: @Scuzzy I tried $object=$output->fetch_object(); var_dump(get_object_vars($object)); For some reasons, it displayed all 4 items instead of just the 1st item. And yours code seems complicated. It will take me sometime to understand it.

Comment: I would really use something like `$row = $output->fetch_assoc(); $key = $row['keyfieldname']; unset($row['keyfieldname']); $results[$key] = $row;` as being far more reliable than trying to get the first key from an associative array or an object as you are *very* dependent on how the driver produces the result as to which is the "first" key.

Comment: @Scuzzy, I want to find out how to do it in object instead. For I don't want to change too much of the code. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will net you the first key from the object property list

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->aaa = 'AAA';
$object->bbb = 'BBB';
$object->ccc = 'CCC';

if( empty( $vars = get_object_vars( $object ) ) === false )
{
  $firstKey = current( array_keys( $vars ) );
  $get = $object->$firstKey; // To get
  unset( $object->$firstKey ); // To remove
  var_dump( $get );
}

var_dump( $object );
```

https://3v4l.org/BmpJ6

```
string(3) "AAA"
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["bbb"]=>
  string(3) "BBB"
  ["ccc"]=>
  string(3) "CCC"
}
```

In the above code, we're using an array of keys `current( array_keys( $vars ) )` you can replace `current` with `end` if you want the first or last key, same way you could also use `array_shift` or `array_pop`